# Cross Thread Static Method Call

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

It's a simple issue and i have found several answered questions on this topic but even after 2 days i still haven't found something that work for this scenario, so i hope someone can help me with this.
This is the method to call on the Main thread, it has to be static unfortunately

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

And on another thread

```
public override void Write(string value)
        {
            //this.console.Invoke(new Action<String, Color>(this.console.AppendText), new Object { value, Color.White });
            //WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => this.console.AppendText(value, Color.White), new Object[] { value, Color.White });
            this.console.AppendText(value, Color.White);
        }
```

I tried implementations with Invoke and SynchronizationContext but can't get it to work right, I'm probably using them wrong, aren't I?

The way the method has to be declared is whats been preventing me from making any of the solutions i found work for me.

Comment: So... what's the problem? Error message? Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Please be more specific than "can't get it to work right" and "preventing me from making any of the solutions i found work". Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a clear, precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. It is doubtful that the problem lies in the `static` aspect or the method declaration, but without a good question, it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: Sorry, its WinForms. Alex's Answer is one exact thing than i tried but it just results in a loop, see comments on that answer

Comment: Ill Update the question with skimmed down complete code, hope that helps, now that i think of it it might be due to the nested classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
On the main thread i had:

```
myHost = new Host(this, Console); //my custom PowerShell implementation
myHost = AddCommand("Write-Host"); //cmdlet to execute
myHost.Run(); // run the Command
```

The call to Run() spawns a child thread down the line witch then tries to write back to a textbox on the main thread. This is where i first ran into the "Illegal Thread Operation error".
A quick google search reveals several ways to make the call thread safe but this call never terminates nor is there any error thrown.
This is because the main thread is waiting on the Run() call to return and thus can't react to the call from the child thread.
The solution was to move the Run(); call to a separete thread so the main thread remains active, then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess, based on the code example you've shown, it *might* be that you misunderstand how the call to a `static` method works. Or maybe it's the fact that the `static` method is an extension method.

In particular, please understand what an extension method actually is: it's really just a plain old static method, which the compiler allows you to call using syntax that makes it *look* like you are calling an instance method. But the method call really is just a static method call and as such requires you to provide all parameters to the method.

If I've guessed correctly, then you can probably get your code to work by changing it to look like this:

```
public override void Write(string value)
{
    this.console.Invoke(
        (Action<RichTextBox, string, Color>)RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText,
        new object[] { this.console, value, Color.White });
}
```

Since the `AppendText()` method is actually a `static` method, you need to provide the method reference explicitly through the class in which it's declared (i.e. `RichTextBoxExtensions`). Calling an extension method via the instance-like syntax works only when that call syntax can be resolved at compile-time, which is not the case for this scenario.

Note that if you don't mind wrapping your method call in another anonymous method, you can simplify the syntax somewhat:

```
public override void Write(string value)
{
    this.console.Invoke(
        (MethodInvoker)(() => this.console.AppendText(value, Color.White)));
}
```

In other words, instead of invoking the `AppendText()` extension method directly, invoke an anonymous method that itself calls the `AppendText()` method using the usual extension method (i.e. instance-like) syntax.

This way, the compiler resolves the instance-like syntax in the body of the anonymous method. The method being invoked is actually the simpler, parameterless anonymous method and so there's no trouble at all getting the exact parameter-passing correct. :)

Comment: I like the fact that you recommend to put the `Invoke` in the caller, not the extension method, keeping with the implementation of other instance methods.

Comment: Looks good but neither of these calls ever hit the breakpoint in the static method...

Comment: @VikFreeze: without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is difficult if not impossible to know for sure what the problem is. Please review the information at the link I've provided here to understand what kind of code example is needed. All I can say based on the information given so far by you is that if the static `AppendText()` method is never called, the UI thread probably is in fact blocked waiting on something else, preventing the cross-thread invocation from completing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: OK i added a way to replicate the problem, you can change `myHost.AddCommand("Write-Host");` to `myHost.AddCommand("dir");` in Form1_Load to seen that it works with synced calls. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @VikFreeze: please re-read the page at the link I provided, so that you understand what is meant by **a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example**. The code you've provided is neither minimal nor complete.

Comment: @PeterDuniho 
    …Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
If i remove any more code you can't run it anymore, Host is a big class that needs two more classes each of witch has to have certain interfaces
    …Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
Should i just upload the entire project files?
    …Verifiable - Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem
I did, that's where the instructions in the post on how to reproduce the problem came from...

Comment: _"If i remove any more code you can't run it anymore"_ -- it is your job to _create_ a suitable code example. No bug ever requires 100% of the code in which it was originally found; typically, less than 1% of the original code is actually relevant, especially when dealing with a large program (such as you apparently are). You need to isolate the bug to a small enough _complete_ code example to be suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: See also http://sscce.org/, http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html, http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/incomplete.html